# ajax.setup() globally for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application. There is an issue with CSRF when ajax calls are made for post requests. I want to append a header with an anti-forgery token on each ajax call. How can I do that globally and not go to each View and add the header on each ajax call? Is it possible? I read about ajax.setup but I don't understand how can I add this to all ajax calls without writing on each View ajax.setup(){... some function here}. I want to do it only in 1 place and work for all Views.

Comment: Yes, I do have one.

Comment: I get your point. I inserted the ajax.setup() in the layout. Thank you :)